# I am getting a 'base(const std::ios_base)' is private error in my code. What is wrong with it?

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

I am getting an error and it happens right at line Chest_vect.push_back(newChest); From my knowledge I don't see anything wrong with it. But I am sure I probably missed something small. If you can help that would be appreciated! Thanks either way!

```
class Chest_objects {

private:
int loc_x, loc_y;
int map_x, map_y;
string obj_name = "";
string obj_id = "";
bool obj_trigger = false;
bool obj_visible = false;

public:

void setLoc_x(int x)
{
 loc_x = x;
}
void setLoc_y(int y)
{
 loc_y = y;
}
                              //OTHER GETTER AND SETTER FUNCTIONS NOT INCLUDED

Chest_objects(int x, int y);  //CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTIONS: NOTE I DON'T HAVE A COMPLETE ONE
Chest_objects();
Chest_objects(int x, int y, int my, int mx, string name, string id, bool trig, bool vis);

int getChestVect(vector<Chest_objects>& Chest_vect, const char*getFile)
{
int amount = 0;
int get_x = 0;
int get_y = 0;
int max_x;
int max_y;
char get_info;
ifstream file;
file.open(getFile);
file >> max_x >> max_y;

while(get_info != '0')
    {
        file >> get_info;
        if(get_info == '.')
        {
        get_x++;
        }
        if(get_info == 'B')
        {
        Chest_objects newChest(get_x, get_y);
        Chest_vect.push_back(newChest);
        get_x++;
        amount++;
        }
        if(get_x >= max_x)
        {
        get_x = 0;
        get_y++;
        }

    }
return amount;
}
};

int main()
{
... blah
return 0;
}

Chest_objects::Chest_objects(int x, int y)
{
loc_x = x;
loc_y = y;
}

 Chest_objects::Chest_objects()
{
loc_x = 0;
loc_y = 0;
}
```

error: In instantiation of 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Chest_objects; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = Chest_objects*]':|

error: 'std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)' is private|

Answer (score 3):

The `push_back` method requires that the type contained in the container be copyable. The error implies that the `Chest_objects` class has only a private constructor. So check that `Chest_objects` has:

- A copy constructor: `Chest_objects(const Chest_objects&);`
- A copy operator: `Chest_objects& operator=(const Chest_objects& rhs);`

and that they are both `public`.

Another possibility is that you subclasses `Chest_objects` from one of the classes in `<iostream>`, which is not recommended, and the compiler's seeing a constructor that takes `std::ios` marked `private`, which means you can't instantiate or subclass it. This can happen with singletons.

*But there's no way to be sure since you didn't post all the code.* Also, before posting code, try to cut out as much code as possible while preserving the error.

---

There's your problem:

```
ifstream small_obj_map;
```

You're instantiating an `ifstream` inside the object. Every object in the `Chest_vect` will have its own `ifstream`. This is almost certainly not what you want.

Since you have not written copy constructors or copy operators, the compiler is trying to create them for you. And the default copy constructor will try to construct `small_obj_map` from the `small_obj_map` of the object being copied. But `ifstream` [has no copy constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/) because *it's not meant to be copied.*

You should instead create the `ifstream` only when you need it, inside the method that needs it, and let it be destroyed when the method exits. It should not be a part of the object because it has no need to persist with the object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I think you are right about the constructor, but not sure exactly. Should I just post the class and the function?

Comment: Post the class's declaration line, including any base classes, and the constructor declarations, and any `operator=` or and typecast operator declarations. And post the *exact* error message, character for character.

Comment: I tried to keep it simple with no operators and a couple of constructors. I declared an override constructor without defining it though. Not sure if that is it. There are no class inheritance in this file.

Comment: It's none of that. It's `small_obj_map` that's breaking you. See my updated answer above.

Comment: So I should use ifstream inside main instead of multiple copies of it that seems to be private inside the class?

Comment: Or you should take the code that uses `ifstream` and make a method out of it. For example, your function is declared as `int getChestVect(vector<Chest_objects>& Chest_vect, ifstream& file, const char*getFile)`, but I see the presence of both the arguments `ifstream& file` and `const char*getFile` as redundant. If the file will be entirely read by the function, and nothing outside needs to continue reading the file from where `getChestVect` left off, then `ifstream& file` is not needed, and should be instantiated in the function with `ifstream file(getFile);` instead of `file.open(getFile);`.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for that information. I didn't realize that as a problem before!